# dual screen configuration fail after login

Tags: 14.04, xorg, multiple-monitors

I would like to setup an offset between my laptop screen and "normal" desktop monitor, so I could see the cursor entering Desktop screen in the same height where it leave laptop screen. I setup it in NVIDIA X server Settings in position, save X configuration File, reboot and viola! It works!

Until... I entered my password and hit enter. After that, all of my settings get back to previous state. Is there any xorg.conf in my home that overrides my settings after login or something like that?

I tried to put my settings into:
* `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
* `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-custom.conf`
* `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-custom.conf`

Everything fails...

60-custom.conf

```
# ablabla                                                                       
# 

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "LVDS-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+512, VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "LVDS-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+535, VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I'm working with

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- `Linux Mephist 3.13.0-46-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:08:14 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`
- XFCE 4.10
- GPU: GeForce Go 7300

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the solution would be to put the same changes into a script, set it as executable and let it run as a startup program.

Comment: How can I 'execute' `xorg.conf` from the script level?

Comment: What I did was that I put this command into startup applications:xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --left-of LVDS1 --output LVDS1 --scale 1.0001x1.0001 somaybe you can modify this into something you need.